# jQuery's .hide() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know why the function `.hide()` is not hiding my div `#cargando` when the div `#tabla` finishes loading.

```
<script>
$(window).load(function () {
    $(function () {
        var url = this.href;
        $("#tabla").load(url, function () {
            $('#cargando').hide();
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Instead of having the hide() function in $(window).load(), place it inside $(document).ready() function. It will work.

Comment: Uhm, what the hell is `this.href` in that context ?

Answer (score 5):

Are You sure that request returns correct response ? Not sure why You are using this.href (href of what ? If site url it would be window.location.href). Install firebug - it will give You full console/network debug informations. Answer for Your question: for 99.9% it's response of "load" function problem.